# How can I order a Django query by a field of a related model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these two models, `ChatRoom` and `ChatMessage`, which are related. My goal is to order the `ChatRoom` queries in a way that the room with the most recent message, as determined by the `sent_timestamp`, appears at the top of the results.

While I've found some similar questions on this platform, none of them seem to precisely address my specific issue.

I'm aware of the annotate method, which I can use to achieve this outside of the model's `Meta` class, but I'm interested in setting the ordering directly in the `Meta` class of the `ChatRoom` model.

Is there a way to achieve this ordering within the Meta class, or is there an alternative approach I should consider?

```py
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="chat_rooms")

    class Meta:
        # Intended for this to order the chat rooms so that the room that
        # has the most recent chat message come first, but it's not working
        ordering = ("-messages__sent_timestamp",)


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, models.CASCADE, related_name="messages")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(280)])
    sent_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    read_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-sent_timestamp",)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ordering = ("-messages__sent_timestamp",)` will introduce *duplication*: for each related `ChatMessage`, the `ChatRoom` will be listed.

You can annotate this with the latest timestamp, and then order by that, so:

```
from django.db.models import Max

ChatRoom.objects.alias(latest=Max('messages__sent_timestamp')).order_by('-latest')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```py
ChatRoom.objects.all().alias(my_order=Max('chatmessage_set__sent_timestamp')).order_by('-my_order')
```

[documentation about aggregations in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request for not using `annotate` and wanting to add this into `Meta`.
I guess you need this ordering to be applied by default on all your queries.

I don't think you can do that in `Meta`
However, you can do that in a `Manager`. and you can use it as a default manager by assigning it to `objects`

```py
# managers.py
class ChatRoomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.alias(latest=Max('messages__sent_timestamp')).order_by('-latest')
        # based on "Willem Van Onsem"'s answer
        return queryset

# models.py
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = ChatRoomManager() # default manager
```

take into consideration that this will add a `join` to all your queries for this model which will result in slower queries based on your data size

if you want to have a way to disable the ordering on-will, you can do the following

```py
# managers.py
class ChatRoomManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, no_ordering: bool = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.no_ordering= no_ordering

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if self.no_ordering:
            return queryset

        queryset = queryset.alias(latest=Max('messages__sent_timestamp')).order_by('-latest')
        return queryset

# models.py
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = ChatRoomManager() # default manager
    raw_objects = ChatRoomManager(no_ordering=True) # original manager
```

hope you find this useful